# How to display rwx permissions with netrw?

Tags: netrw

In vim, how can I display the `rwx` (i.e., permissions) of files and/or directories using `netrw`? For example, I'd like to do this:

1. vim
2. :Ex
3. (see output like ls -l)

The closest thing I know is, in step 3, to press `i`, which shows this:

```
USR3SA9P89W.TXT*                    14830 Tue 14 Mar 2017 08:03:48 AM CDT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to do this such that the full listing will show file permissions. However you can see extra information, including permissions, for individual files. Put the cursor on a file/directory and type `qf`.

As a simple, non-netrw solution you could always run `ls -l` through the shell. For instance, to "long-list" the directory in which the current buffer resides...

```
:!ls -l %:p:h
```